# Solution Form to Differential Inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential inequality:

$$2\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}+\left[\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}\right]^2+f(x)\cdot[g(x)]^2 < 0$$

Can you recommend a solution for $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$?

Comment: The idea would be to think of the LHS expression as a quadratic in $\frac{dg}{dx}$. Use the quadratic formula to give a factored form.

Comment: Another idea is to use $g'(x)^2\ge 0$ to get $2g'+fg^2<0$, which is easy to solve.